# How can I format numbers in the view with commas and strip those before saving?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I've got a few model attributes that I need to format differently in the view. Namely dollar amounts that need commas and bandwidth that's stored in bytes but needs to be displayed in gigabytes. My view is editable inline, meaning you can click a field, change the contents, then hit "Enter" to save. So these values will need to be "cleaned" before saving the model.

What is the best way to manage the "prettifying" of this data in the view while keeping the source formatted as the model/db expects it?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you gave an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone ModelBinder allows exactly this capability; my team relies on it pretty heavily for currency entries.

https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder#formatting-and-converting-values